# generate table in java 

Tags: java, string

I am trying to create table in java by taking in user input. So for the three the table should look like:

I am looking for any idea on how to go about doing this - may be just pseudo code would be helpful I can fill in the blanks. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Javascript code to do what you want:

```
var input = 3; // Read 3 from user
var lines = 1 << input;
var i, j;

for(i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    var str = "";
    for(j = input - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        if(i & 1 << j)
             str += "1";
        else
             str += "0";
    }
    document.write(str + "<br />");
}
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/uqP3M/

I won't give you Java code since this is probably homework and you should try to understand it while converting it to Java. If you are unsure of the `<<` operator. Just know that `(1 << x)` means 2 to the power of x. That should help you understand it.

Comment: Let me know if you have any trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use loop from 0 to 2^n - 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << n; i++) {
    // print i in binary form
    // (print only the last n bits)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try recursion.
The method would accept a string and then recurse, either adding a 0 or a 1, until a max size is found, at that point it prints out the value and return.

```
method(string a, int max)
{
  if (stopping condition reached?)
  {
    print(a);
  }
  else
  {
    recurse with 0 + a
    recurse with 1 + a
  }
}
```

I've tried leaving it open so there's still work for you to do

Comment: the problem is I don't know when to add a zero or a one. like I had the recursion part in my head but I don't know how to set up the recursion.

Comment: Keep in mind that "adding" should probably mean "inserting at the beginning" if the ordering stated in the example is required.

Comment: Recursion is total overkill here.

Comment: You need to do both, one at a time. The first recursive call will branch out until all values on that branch are tried, then you are back at the function and the second recursive call will be made, which branches out until all values on that branch are made.

Comment: @Oli His prof is probably trying to get him to learn it through this example though.

Comment: @Jean: Where do you get that impression?  This can be solved trivially by iterating from 0 to max, and printing each one in binary.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth To me, the padding of 0's that solution would require is more work than thinking recursively.

Comment: @Jean: Really? It's two nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant, but it produces the values you describe.  Not input validation or anything, so there is room for improvement.

```
  // This should be set as input, hardcoding for example
  int lines = 3;

  char[] fill = new char[lines];
  Arrays.fill(fill, '0');

  String resultTemplate = new String(fill);
  int maxNum = (int) Math.pow(2, lines);

  for(int index = 0; index < maxNum;index++)
  {
     String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(index);
     System.out.println(resultTemplate.substring(0,lines-binaryString.length()) + binaryString);
  }
```

Comment: The more elegant - and imo standard - solution would be to use `printf()` and the correct formatting options to get zero padding. Maybe also get rid of the math.pow but maybe that just seems more obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n=3,length;
String front="";
for (int i = 0; i < 1 << n; i++) {
    front="";
    String bin= Integer.toBinaryString(i);
    if((length=n-bin.length())>0) front=new String(new char[length]).replace("\0", "0");
    System.out.println(front+bin);
}
```

Output:

000
001
010
011
100
101
110
111

Answer (score -1):

```
package javaa;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MulTable {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int n = 0,x = 0;
        do
        {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("start range:");
            x = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("enter the end  range:");
            n = sc.nextInt();

            for(int i = x; i <= n; i++)
            {

                for(int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    System.out.println(i + "*" + j + "=" + (i*j));
                }
            }
        }
        while((n!=9)||(x!=9));

    }
}
```

Comment: if u enter the range u will get output ..of multiplication table